# In Catan, is it possible to steal from yourself with the robber?

Tags: catan

If I move the robber in Catan to a hex where I also have an adjacent settlement or city on, can I choose to steal from myself instead of another player or if I am the only valid player?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but the same answer is given in one of the answers here: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/avoiding-stealing-a-resource-when-moving-the-robber-in-catan

Comment: it is not a duplicate, this is about yourself as a target and the other one is about other players being invalid targets

Comment: @ivar de bruin; the other one is about a general method of not stealing; one answer point out that choosing yourself is one option. I agree that it's probably not a duplicate; but the other question is certainly relevant (considering that the only reason to want to steal from yourself is as an method of avoiding stealing from others).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, you may not.**

According to the [official rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf) on the website:

> (1) You must move the robber immediately to the number token of any
> other terrain hex or to the desert hex.
>
> (2) Then you steal 1 (random)
> Resource Card from an **opponent** who has a settlement or city adjacent
> to the target terrain hex. The player who is robbed holds his Resource
> Card hand face down. You then take 1 at random. If the target hex is
> adjacent to 2 or more players’ settlements or cities, you choose which
> one you want to rob.

One could argue the second part "if ...adjacent to 2 players'", but I find that interpretation completely mis-aligns with the unambiguous previous rule that you do not and would not rob *yourself*.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: Apparently my version of the rules is outdated

Comment: I know hexparrot went to the trouble of linking the official pdf of the rules and copying them out, but **no, it shouldn't be marked as the correct answer**. There is no requirement at all that the robber be moved to a hex adjacent to an opponent. The robber may be moved to a hex completely apart from any player or to a hex only bordered by the player's village(s). Blocking your own villages' resources is terrible gameplay, "stealing from yourself" doesn't make any sense, and it isn't permitted *if* there *is* another player's village adjacent to the robber...

Comment: ...but, yes, you can effectively "steal from yourself" by moving the robber away or to a hex only bordered by your own villages as a matter of hospitality.

Comment: @lly I don't understand your argument.  I *never* claimed you are required to place the robber on a hex adjacent to an opponent.  It seems clear from the rules that you need only move the robber to another hex--and should you choose one without a player present--so be it.  Just like if you were to move it to the desert hex.

And to your second comment "you can effectively 'steal from yourself'" seems explicitly wrong in light of the rule: "you steal 1 Resource card from an *opponent*".  I address this with my own interpretation below the official rule citation.

Comment: Keep in mind: "stealing from yourself" is very different from "denying yourself a future resource".  The part about "the player who is robbed" seems really ridiculous if you were to play that out as yourself both the robber *and* the victim.

Comment: You're correct to point out that, under the current official rules, @NickyNg shouldn't opt to steal from himself if there's an opponent nearby. You're mistaken he can't declare that he's stealing from himself via the legal (though counterproductive) move of placing the robber in a hex only adjacent to his town. The rules don't need to belabor that point since 'stealing a card from himself' simply leaves it in his own hand.

Comment: The net effect may be zero--by stealing from yourself, returning it to yourself--but that would be directly in opposition to the previous line stating you steal from an _opponent_. The "if the target hex..." part does not need to "belabor the point" that it means 2+ *opponents*, rather than "one opponent...and yourself". It seems like a willfully dishonest interpretation to see that you can opt _not_ to steal from an opponent simply because _you_ are adjacent.  Instead, it seems that they just chose a noun that could have easily been 'opponent', as the first rule isn't disregarded.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the rules state that:

> After discarding occurs, you also steal 1 resource card at random from **a player** who has a settlement or city adjacent to this hex

You are also a player, so you can steal from yourself

Comment: Note that although this is allowed, it is better to place the robber on the desert, rather than on yourself, since then the robber isn't preventing you from getting resources.

Comment: There is the situation that you want to block the other players on the Hex, but not steal from them

Comment: Oh, you're saying that you share tiles with other players. Yeah, I suppose that might be a reason to block yourself.

Comment: If you have 2 brick and the other only one that can be a good play